# Cannot create new opportunity in Vtiger? incorrect integer value

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Could you please give me a hand to correct the error when I created new opportunity in Vtiger CRM.

The cause is "incorrect integer value '' when system insert '' into int field.
There is solution to solve it by set sql mode. But I'm using shared hosting. Provider cannot to do this one.

Answer (score 0):

In vtiger by default it use mysqli as DB type which will be defined in config.inc.php file

```
$dbconfig['db_type'] = 'mysqli';
```

I would suggest you to set SQL mode runtime by defining this line in Library file which vtiger using for DB connection

```
\vtiger\libraries\adodb\drivers\adodb-mysqli.inc.php
```

Add on line code at line no 126

Previous code

```
if ($ok) {
        if ($argDatabasename)  return $this->SelectDB($argDatabasename);
        return true;
} else {
        if ($this->debug)
            ADOConnection::outp("Could't connect : "  . $this->ErrorMsg());
        $this->_connectionID = null;
        return false;
}
```

Latest Code

```
if ($ok) {
        mysqli_query($this->_connectionID, "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL'");
        if ($argDatabasename)  return $this->SelectDB($argDatabasename);
        return true;
} else {
        if ($this->debug)
            ADOConnection::outp("Could't connect : "  . $this->ErrorMsg());
        $this->_connectionID = null;
        return false;
}
```

Hope this helps you